# Информация о принтере

Tags: windows, java

Привет.

Как в Java можно получить информацию о принтере? Класс, имя и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinspoolUtil;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Winspool;
Winspool.PRINTER_INFO_4 info=WinspoolUtil.getPrinterInfo4();
for (Winspool.PRINTER_INFO_4 k : info) {
    k.read();
    System.out.println(k.toString());
};
```

это та информация, которая и Вас в вопросе до «и т.д.».
 О том как получить прочую информацию о принтере с помощью win32 API  можно прочитать [по этой ссылке](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.thedbcommunity.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26task%3Dview%26id%3D218%26Itemid%3D56&btnG=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=)
Вызвать функции win32 API Вам поможет опять же JNA. 
[JNA на Github](https://github.com/twall/jna),
[JNA JavaDoc](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

достаточно подробное описание на английском, там же есть несколько полезных ссылок:
[java world](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1020-print.html)

Comment: спасибо .. но это не то ... тут только, как устанавливать параметры и печатать на принтере